# Formatting a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I have created a temporary table with two fields, formatted to int.
create table #tmp

```
unprocessed int, 
invoiced int
```

I am then calculating a third field with this.

```
select unprocessed, invoiced, (unprocessed /invoiced) as percentageunprocessed 
from #tmp
```

My result is

```
Unprocessed   invoiced percentageunprocessed
33            200       0
```

It should be

```
33            200       0.165
```

I think this is because the percentageunprocessed is also formatted as int and not dec (5,2). Can I change the format?

Comment: Strange, my MYSQL gives a float? What version of MYSQL are you using

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Fiddle your code at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c50bc1/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Its not the Answer:

it not normal. normal its return a float

**my version**

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.15    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**sample**

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result (a INT, b INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO result VALUES(10,330);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT a,b,a/b FROM result;
+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | a/b    |
+------+------+--------+
|   10 |  330 | 0.0303 |
+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```